# Finding a tangent line with implicit differentiatio

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find the tangent line on point $P$ for this curve
$(x + 2)^2 + (y - 3)^2 = 37$ on $P(4,4)$

---

I tried implicit differentiating

$2(x + 2) + 2(y - 3)y' = 0$

I'm not sure if solving for $y'$ is the way, though

$$y' = \frac{-2(x + 2)}{2(y - 3)}$$
$$y' = -6$$

What do you think?

UPDATE

then

$$y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$$
$$y - 4 = -6(x - 4)$$
$$y = -6x + 28$$

Comment: The derivative of $(y-3)^2$ is $2(y-3)y'$ (now fixed).  Then solving and then substituting is OK, though I prefer to substitute then solve.

Comment: Answer should be $y' = \frac{-(x + 2)}{(y - 3)}$

Comment: OK so can you finish it? BTW you don't need calculus for this job...

Answer (score 1):

implicit-differentiation
$$f(x,y)=0 \\y'=-\frac{f'_x(x,y)}{f'_y(x,y)}=- \frac{f'_x}{f'_y}$$
if you apply it on $$(x+2)^2+(y−3)^2-37=0=f(x,y)\\y'=-\frac{2(x+2)}{2(y-3)}$$ then put $p(4,4)$ $$y'=-\frac{(x+2)}{y-3}=-\frac{4+2}{4-3}=-6$$